# Menu Parser in C

Tags: c, parsing

This is a simple program that parses a menu specification and creates a menu tree.

Why?
I want to create a menu application, where the user can select an entry in the menu, and either a submenu can pop up (where the user can select another entry) or a command is run.

But before writing this menu thing (which requires some coding using Xlib), I need to write a parser for the menu configuration file. And I'm not used to write parsers.

Suppose this is a menu configuration file:

```
_Apps {
    Draw Terminal                           -- exec drawterm
    Open _Terminal at $HOME [^T]            -- exec xterm
    Open Terminal Here [^S-T]               -- exec samedir
    Take _Screenshot                        -- exec scrot select
    _Run                                    -- exec runner
    File _Manager                           -- exec run fm
    _Firefox                                -- exec run www
    _Chrome                                 -- exec chrome
    C_hat                                   -- exec hexchat
    _Games {
        TES III _Morowind               -- exec openmw
        GNU _Backgammon [^S-B]          -- exec gnubg
        _Spider                         -- exec spider
        Super Tux _Kart                 -- exec supertuxkart
    }
}

_Window {
    Stic_k Container                        -- exec shodc state -y
    S_hade Container                        -- exec shodc state -s
    Minimi_ze Container                     -- exec shodc state -m
    _Maximize Container [^W]                -- exec shodc state -M
    Container _FullScreen                   -- exec shodc state -f
    Container _Below                        -- exec shodc state -b
    Container _Above                        -- exec shodc state -a
    Move Container _To {
        Move to Desktop _1              -- exec shodc sendto 1
        Move to Desktop _2              -- exec shodc sendto 2
        Move to Desktop _3              -- exec shodc sendto 3
        Move to Desktop _4              -- exec shodc sendto 4
        Move to Desktop _5              -- exec shodc sendto 5
    }
    _Focus {
        Focus Column on the _Left [^H]  -- exec shodc focus -L
        Focus Column on the _Right [^L] -- exec shodc focus -R
        Focus Row _Above [^K]           -- exec shodc focus -T
        Focus Row _Below [^J]           -- exec shodc focus -B
        Focus Previous Tab [^P]         -- exec shodc focus -cP
        Focus Next Tab [^N]             -- exec shodc focus -cN
    }
    _Close Window [^S-Q]                    -- exec shodc close
}

_Music {
    _Next song                              -- exec mpc next
    _Stop song                              -- exec mpc stop
    _Previous song                          -- exec mpc cdprev
    _Toggle Pause/Play                      -- exec mpc toggle
}
```

In this hypothetical menu system, when this config file is given, a menu will always be visible for the user. Then, if he clicks the `Apps` menu, another menu will pop up, where the user can open the `Games` submenu, popping up another menu, in which the user can select `GNU Backgammon`, and then the string `exec gnubg` will be passed to `sh -c`, effectively opening the GNU Backgammon program.

[image: illustration]

Another way to open GNU Backgammon is to type the keys `Alt` then `A`, then `G`, then `B`, in this order, effectively navigating through the menus. This is called the *Alt Sequence*.

Yet another way to open GNU Backgammon is to press `Ctrl + Shift + B`. This is called the *Accelerator keychord*.

But this program is not the menu system, it's just a parser for its configuration file.
I just wanted to give you the background for it.

The parser is split into three `.c` files and a single `.h` file.  And it just builds a tree of `Entry` structures, and print them out.

`ctrlmenu.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "ctrlmenu.h"

static void
printentries(struct Entry *entry, int lvl)
{
    int i;
    for (; entry != NULL; entry = entry->next) {
        for (i = 0; i < lvl; i++)
            printf("\t");
        printf("%s", entry->name);
        if (entry->alt != NULL)
            printf(" (%s)", entry->alt);
        if (entry->cmd != NULL)
            printf(" : %s", entry->cmd);
        printf("\n");
        if (entry->children != NULL) {
            printentries(entry->children, lvl + 1);
        }
    }
}

static void
printaccelerators(struct Accelerator *acc)
{
    printf("\n");
    for (; acc != NULL; acc = acc->next) {
        if (acc->mods & ControlMask)
            printf("Ctrl + ");
        if (acc->mods & ShiftMask)
            printf("Shift + ");
        printf("%s: %s\n", acc->keyname, acc->entry->name);
    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    struct Entry *entries = NULL;
    struct Accelerator *accs = NULL;

    /* commented out code for later version */
    //xinit();
    entries = readfile(stdin, "-", &accs);
    printf("\n");
    //runmenu(menu);
    printentries(entries, 0);
    printaccelerators(accs);
    cleanentries(entries);
    cleanaccelerators(accs);
    //xclose();
}
```

`parse.c`:

```c
#include <err.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "ctrlmenu.h"

#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define UTFMAX  4

/* token types */
enum {
    TOK_NONE        = '\0',
    TOK_NEWLINE     = '\n',
    TOK_CMD         = 'C',
    TOK_NAME        = 'N',
    TOK_OPENCURLY   = '{',
    TOK_CLOSECURLY  = '}',
    TOK_OPENSQUARE  = '[',
    TOK_CLOSESQUARE = ']',
    TOK_ASTERISK    = '*',
    TOK_CARET       = '^',
    TOK_COMMA       = ',',
    TOK_ACCEL       = '_',
    TOK_WHITESPACE  = ' ',
    TOK_EOF         = -1,
};

/* parsedata for reentrant parsing */
struct ParseData {
    /* housekeeping data */
    FILE *fp;
    char *filename;
    size_t lineno;
    int eof;

    /* the token buffer */
    char *bufdata;
    int bufsize;
    int bufindex;

    /* the token itself */
    int toktype;
    char *toktext;
    size_t toksize;
};

static struct Entry *parselist(struct ParseData *parse, struct Accelerator **accs);

static int
efgets(struct ParseData *parse)
{
    if (fgets(parse->bufdata, parse->bufsize, parse->fp) == NULL) {
        if (ferror(parse->fp))
            err(1, "fgets");
        parse->eof = 1;
        return EOF;
    }
    return '\0';
}

static void
readtok(struct ParseData *parse, int isname)
{
    size_t nread, i;
    int eot;                        /* whether we reach end of token */
    int inc;                        /* whether to increment bufindex */

    eot = 0;
    i = 0;
    nread = 1;
    while (!eot) {
        while (isblank((unsigned char)parse->bufdata[parse->bufindex]))
            parse->bufindex++;
        nread += strlen(&parse->bufdata[parse->bufindex]);
        if (parse->toksize < nread) {
            if (parse->toksize == 0)
                parse->toksize = parse->bufsize;
            else
                parse->toksize <<= 1;
            parse->toktext = erealloc(parse->toktext, parse->toksize);
        }
        while (parse->bufdata[parse->bufindex] != '\0') {
            inc = 1;
            if (strchr("{}\n", parse->bufdata[parse->bufindex]) != NULL) {
                parse->toktext[i] = '\0';
                eot = 1;
                break;
            } else if (isname && parse->bufdata[parse->bufindex] == '-' && parse->bufdata[parse->bufindex+1] == '-') {
                parse->toktext[i] = '\0';
                eot = 1;
                break;
            } else if (parse->bufdata[parse->bufindex] == '\\') {
                switch (parse->bufdata[++parse->bufindex]) {
                case 'a':
                    parse->toktext[i++] = '\a';
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    parse->toktext[i++] = '\b';
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    parse->toktext[i++] = '\f';
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    parse->toktext[i++] = '\n';
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    parse->toktext[i++] = '\r';
                    break;
                case 't':
                    parse->toktext[i++] = '\t';
                    break;
                case '\n':
                    if (efgets(parse) == EOF) {
                        warnx("%s:%zu: parse error: unexpected end of file", parse->filename, parse->lineno);
                        eot = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    parse->lineno++;
                    parse->bufindex = 0;
                    inc = 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    parse->toktext[i++] = parse->bufdata[parse->bufindex];
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                parse->toktext[i++] = parse->bufdata[parse->bufindex];
            }
            if (inc) {
                parse->bufindex++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (i > 0) {
        while (isblank((unsigned char)parse->toktext[i-1]))
            i--;
    }
    parse->toktext[i] = '\0';
}

static void
advance(struct ParseData *parse)
{
    if (parse->bufdata[parse->bufindex] == '\0') {
        /* if there's no data in the buffer, fill it with more data */
        if (efgets(parse) == EOF) {
            parse->toktype = TOK_EOF;
            parse->eof = 1;
            return;
        }
        parse->lineno++;
        parse->bufindex = 0;
    }
    while (isblank((unsigned char)parse->bufdata[parse->bufindex]))
        parse->bufindex++;
    if (strchr("{}\n", parse->bufdata[parse->bufindex]) != NULL) {
        parse->toktype = parse->bufdata[parse->bufindex++];
    } else if (parse->bufdata[parse->bufindex] == '-' && parse->bufdata[parse->bufindex + 1] == '-') {
        /* we got two dashes, read command into toktext */
        parse->bufindex += 2;
        parse->toktype = TOK_CMD;
        readtok(parse, 0);
    } else {
        parse->toktype = TOK_NAME;
        readtok(parse, 1);
    }
}

static int
gettok(struct ParseData *parse)
{
    int rettype;

    if (parse->eof)
        return TOK_EOF;
    else if (parse->toktype == TOK_NONE)
        advance(parse);
    rettype = parse->toktype;
    parse->toktype = TOK_NONE;
    return rettype;
}

static void
ungettok(struct ParseData *parse, int toktype)
{
    parse->toktype = toktype;
}

static int
check(struct ParseData *parse, int expected)
{
    int gottype;

    gottype = gettok(parse);
    ungettok(parse, gottype);
    return gottype == expected;
}

static void
consume(struct ParseData *parse, int expected)
{
    static char *toktab[] = {
        [TOK_NAME]        = "entry name",
        [TOK_OPENCURLY]   = "\"{\"",
        [TOK_CLOSECURLY]  = "\"}\"",
        [TOK_OPENSQUARE]  = "\"[\"",
        [TOK_CLOSESQUARE] = "\"]\"",
        [TOK_ASTERISK]    = "\"*\"",
        [TOK_CARET]       = "\"^\"",
        [TOK_COMMA]       = "\",\"",
        [TOK_ACCEL]       = "key chord",
        [TOK_CMD]         = "command",
        [TOK_WHITESPACE]  = "whitespace",
        [TOK_NEWLINE]     = "newline",
    };
    int gottype;

    if ((gottype = gettok(parse)) != expected) {
        warnx(
            "%s:%zu: parse error: expected %s; got %s",
            parse->filename,
            parse->lineno,
            toktab[expected],
            toktab[gottype]
        );
        parse->bufindex = 0;
        parse->bufdata[0] = '\0';
    }
}

static struct Accelerator *
addaccelerator(char *str, int ctrl, int shift, struct Entry *entry)
{
    struct Accelerator *acc;

    acc = emalloc(sizeof(*acc));
    *acc = (struct Accelerator){
        .next = NULL,
        .mods = 0,
    };
    if (ctrl)
        acc->mods |= ControlMask;
    if (shift)
        acc->mods |= ShiftMask;
    acc->entry = entry;
    acc->keyname = estrdup(str);
    return acc;
}

static void
parsename(struct ParseData *parse, struct Entry *entry, struct Accelerator **accs)
{
    static const unsigned char utfbyte[] = {0x80, 0x00, 0xC0, 0xE0, 0xF0};
    static const unsigned char utfmask[] = {0xC0, 0x80, 0xE0, 0xF0, 0xF8};
    struct Accelerator *acc;
    size_t i, n;
    int ctrl, shift;
    char *s, *p;

    consume(parse, TOK_NAME);
    if ((s = strchr(parse->toktext, '_')) != NULL) {
        /* read alt sequence */
        s++;
        n = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < UTFMAX; i++) {
            if (((unsigned char)*s & utfmask[i]) == utfbyte[i]) {
                n++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (n > 0 && i < UTFMAX) {
            entry->alt = estrndup(s, n);
            memmove(s - 1, s, strlen(s) + 1);
        }
    }
    if ((s = strchr(parse->toktext, '[')) != NULL) {
        /* read accelerator keychord */
        if (s <= parse->toktext) {
            warnx("%s:%zu: parse error: empty entry name", parse->filename, parse->lineno);
            return;
        }
        *s = '\0';
        for (p = s - 1; p > parse->toktext && isblank(*(unsigned char *)p); p--)
            *p = '\0';
        s++;
        n = strcspn(s, "]");
        if (s[n] != ']' || s[n + 1] != '\0') {
            warnx("%s:%zu: parse error: unmatching square braces", parse->filename, parse->lineno);
            return;
        }
        s[n] = '\0';
        for (p = strtok(s, " \t"); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, " \t")) {
            ctrl = *(p++) = '^';
            shift = 0;
            if (p[0] == 'S' && p[1] == '-') {
                shift = 1;
                p += 2;
            }
            acc = addaccelerator(p, ctrl, shift, entry);
            acc->next = *accs;
            *accs = acc;
        }
    }
    entry->name = estrdup(parse->toktext);
}

static void
parsecmd(struct ParseData *parse, struct Entry *entry)
{
    consume(parse, TOK_CMD);
    entry->cmd = estrdup(parse->toktext);
}

static struct Entry *
parseentry(struct ParseData *parse, struct Accelerator **accs)
{
    struct Entry *entry;

    entry = emalloc(sizeof(*entry));
    *entry = (struct Entry){
        .prev = NULL,
        .next = NULL,
        .children = NULL,
        .name = NULL,
        .cmd = NULL,
        .alt = NULL,
    };
    parsename(parse, entry, accs);
    if (check(parse, TOK_CMD)) {
        parsecmd(parse, entry);
    }
    if (check(parse, TOK_OPENCURLY)) {
        consume(parse, TOK_OPENCURLY);
        entry->children = parselist(parse, accs);
        consume(parse, TOK_CLOSECURLY);
    }
    consume(parse, TOK_NEWLINE);
    return entry;
}

static struct Entry *
parselist(struct ParseData *parse, struct Accelerator **accs)
{
    struct Entry *entry, *entries, *last;
    int toktype;

    entries = last = NULL;
    while((toktype = gettok(parse)) != TOK_EOF && toktype != TOK_CLOSECURLY) {
        if (toktype == TOK_NEWLINE)     /* consume blank lines */
            continue;
        ungettok(parse, toktype);
        if ((entry = parseentry(parse, accs)) == NULL)
            break;
        if (entries == NULL)
            entries = entry;
        if (last != NULL)
            last->next = entry;
        entry->prev = last;
        last = entry;
    }
    ungettok(parse, toktype);
    return entries;
}

void
cleanentries(struct Entry *entry)
{
    struct Entry *tmp;

    while (entry != NULL) {
        tmp = entry;
        entry = entry->next;
        if (tmp->name != NULL)
            free(tmp->name);
        if (tmp->cmd != NULL)
            free(tmp->cmd);
        if (tmp->alt != NULL)
            free(tmp->alt);
        if (tmp->children != NULL) {
            cleanentries(tmp->children);
        }
        free(tmp);
    }
}

void
cleanaccelerators(struct Accelerator *acc)
{
    struct Accelerator *tmp;

    while (acc != NULL) {
        tmp = acc;
        acc = acc->next;
        if (tmp->keyname != NULL)
            free(tmp->keyname);
        free(tmp);
    }
}

struct Entry *
readfile(FILE *fp, char *filename, struct Accelerator **accs)
{
    struct Entry *entries;
    struct ParseData parse;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];

    buf[0] = '\0';
    parse = (struct ParseData){
        .fp = fp,
        .filename = filename,
        .lineno = 0,
        .eof = 0,

        .bufdata = buf,
        .bufsize = BUFSIZE,

        .toktype = TOK_NONE,
        .toktext = NULL,
        .toksize = 0,
    };
    entries = parselist(&parse, accs);
    free(parse.toktext);
    return entries;
}
```

`util.c`:

```
#include <err.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
max(int x, int y)
{
    return x > y ? x : y;
}

int
min(int x, int y)
{
    return x < y ? x : y;
}

void *
emalloc(size_t size)
{
    void *p;

    if ((p = malloc(size)) == NULL)
        err(1, "malloc");
    return p;
}

void *
ecalloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
    void *p;

    if ((p = calloc(nmemb, size)) == NULL)
        err(1, "calloc");
    return p;
}

void *
erealloc(void *ptr, size_t size)
{
    void *p;

    if ((p = realloc(ptr, size)) == NULL)
        err(1, "realloc");
    return p;
}

char *
estrdup(const char *s)
{
    char *t;

    if ((t = strdup(s)) == NULL)
        err(1, "strdup");
    return t;
}

char *
estrndup(const char *s, size_t maxlen)
{
    char *t;

    if ((t = strndup(s, maxlen)) == NULL)
        err(1, "strndup");
    return t;
}
```

`ctrlmenu.h`:

```c
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

/* menu entry structure */
struct Entry {
    struct Entry *prev, *next;
    struct Entry *children;
    char *name;                     /* entry name */
    char *cmd;                      /* command entered */
    char *alt;                      /* alternative key sequence */
};

struct Accelerator {
    struct Accelerator *next;
    struct Entry *entry;
    unsigned int mods;
    char *keyname;                  /* accelerator key */
};

extern Display *dpy;

/* parse.c */
struct Entry *readfile(FILE *fp, char *filename, struct Accelerator **accs);
void cleanentries(struct Entry *entry);
void cleanaccelerators(struct Accelerator *accs);

/* x.c */
// void xinit(void);
// void xclose(void);

/* util.c */
int max(int x, int y);
int min(int x, int y);
void *emalloc(size_t size);
void *ecalloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
void *erealloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
char *estrdup(const char *s);
char *estrndup(const char *s, size_t maxlen);
```

You may need to include some X11/Xlib headers for the `ControlMask` and `ShiftMask` constants to be defined (or just define them to `0x1` and `0x2`).

Since the program is not complete, there are some code commented out (especially those calling x functions in an innexistant `x.o` module), and there are some unused functions in `util.o`.

When that input file is given on its stdin, the program will first print the menu structure, and then print the accelerators:

```
Apps (A)
    Draw Terminal : exec drawterm
    Open Terminal at $HOME (T) : exec xterm
    Open Terminal Here : exec samedir
    Take Screenshot (S) : exec scrot select
    Run (R) : exec runner
    File Manager (M) : exec run fm
    Firefox (F) : exec run www
    Chrome (C) : exec chrome
    Chat (h) : exec hexchat
    Games (G)
        TES III Morowind (M) : exec openmw
        GNU Backgammon (B) : exec gnubg
        Spider (S) : exec spider
        Super Tux Kart (K) : exec supertuxkart
Window (W)
    Stick Container (k) : exec shodc state -y
    Shade Container (h) : exec shodc state -s
    Minimize Container (z) : exec shodc state -m
    Maximize Container (M) : exec shodc state -M
    Container FullScreen (F) : exec shodc state -f
    Container Below (B) : exec shodc state -b
    Container Above (A) : exec shodc state -a
    Move Container To (T)
        Move to Desktop 1 (1) : exec shodc sendto 1
        Move to Desktop 2 (2) : exec shodc sendto 2
        Move to Desktop 3 (3) : exec shodc sendto 3
        Move to Desktop 4 (4) : exec shodc sendto 4
        Move to Desktop 5 (5) : exec shodc sendto 5
    Focus (F)
        Focus Column on the Left (L) : exec shodc focus -L
        Focus Column on the Right (R) : exec shodc focus -R
        Focus Row Above (A) : exec shodc focus -T
        Focus Row Below (B) : exec shodc focus -B
        Focus Previous Tab : exec shodc focus -cP
        Focus Next Tab : exec shodc focus -cN
    Close Window (C) : exec shodc close
Music (M)
    Next song (N) : exec mpc next
    Stop song (S) : exec mpc stop
    Previous song (P) : exec mpc cdprev
    Toggle Pause/Play (T) : exec mpc toggle

Ctrl + Shift + Q: Close Window
Ctrl + N: Focus Next Tab
Ctrl + P: Focus Previous Tab
Ctrl + J: Focus Row Below
Ctrl + K: Focus Row Above
Ctrl + L: Focus Column on the Right
Ctrl + H: Focus Column on the Left
Ctrl + W: Maximize Container
Ctrl + Shift + B: GNU Backgammon
Ctrl + Shift + T: Open Terminal Here
Ctrl + T: Open Terminal at $HOME
```

Is this parser good?
Should I rewrite it in yacc(1) and/or lex(1)?

Comment: `yacc` would probably be much less code in your parser, but would that matter?